PySpark UDF with return type based on inputs
I'm trying to find a way to write a PySpark UDF which can support any input types and return a type based on the types of the inputs. For example, say I wanted to create a simple clamp function, which just clamps a numeric value to be between lower and upper bounds. It could be written like so:
def clamp(value, low, high):
    return max(low, min(value, high))

This function should be able to support any numeric type. But the pyspark.sql.functions.udf function allows you to only specify a single return type, and if the type doesn't match, then udf return NULL. I tried to play around with overload from the typing module, but I couldn't get it to work. I know it must be possible somehow because functions such as pyspark.sql.functions.sum work for any numeric type, but I can't seem to replicate it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm not sure if it is possible to do it on PySpark, but in your example, you should not do it using UDFs, given they are way slower, and this can be done using normal pyspark functions for generating columns, for example:
lambda value, low, high:  sql_functions.max(low, sql_functions.min(value, high))

Clamp is just a simple example. There's a ton of potential use cases where something like this would be really handy, since creating separate UDFs for every type is not ideal.

After a bunch of experimentation, I created a rough solution for anyone who might be interested. It doesn't quite do what I'm looking for, but it's close, and someone smarter than me might be able to improve upon it. Basically, I created a decorator that wraps the function and creates the UDF when the function is called, rather than created. Here's the code:
class variable_udf:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.cache = {}

    def __call__(self, *args, return_type=StringType(), **kwargs):
        if return_type not in self.cache:
            self.cache[return_type] = F.udf(self.func, return_type)
        return self.cache[return_type](*args, **kwargs)

Then you can create your function and call it like this:
@variable_udf
def clamp(value, low, high):
    return max(low, min(value, high))

df = df.select(clamp("col1", "col2", "col3", return_type=DoubleType()).alias("result"))

I haven't done any performance testing or anything, so I'm not sure how well it performs, but I'm hoping the use of the cache at least helps. This particular example also requires that all the columns be the same type for some reason. If low and high are ints, but the return type is double, then the result is null. Not sure why that is.
